# Proper REST URI date range

Tags: rest, uri

Which date range format would be more preferable in a REST URI?  I prefer the first one. However, I have seen compressed timestamps as well. Thoughts?

```
api.example.com/report/id?start=2015-08-07&end=2015-08-15
api.example.com/report/id?start=20150807&end=20150815
api.example.com/report/id?range=20150807-20150815
```

Answer (score 1):

To state that it is proper or preferable would be overstating my case but I have had success with the following which is based upon the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. with `..` as a range separator.  I have used this both as a URL segment and for query parameters in the past.  Pick that which fits your requirements most closely, I would consider the time portion optional.

```
2012-01-01T00:00:00.000Z..2012-12-31T00:00:00.000Z
```